# Insert of generic values in HashMap C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, generics, hashmap

I have a function(`create`) in order to create an *hashmap*.

My hashmap is bigger than 11 , but this is an example and I'm searching to make code more clearly as possible.

The hashmap will contain a couple *KEY-VALUE* in each node. My aim is to create a *generic Insert function* in which I can insert `int`, `char` etc... from an array.

In my example I insert Int `Insert` Function takes as parameters `Table t` (where I insert `int` that i created before), two pointers to values that I must insert, the position in which I have to insert values in the hashmap and `compare` function passed by user, in order to compare two keys and return 1 if they are equal. The trouble is : when I try to print the hashmap (`print(t)`) it return in each position last couple inserted.

**input**
My arr[11] and arr2[11]

**expected output**

```
key: 1,val: 11
key: 2,val: 10
key: 3,val: 9
key: 4,val: 8
key: 5,val: 7
key: 6,val: 6
key: 7,val: 5
key: 8,val: 4
key: 9,val: 3
key: 10,val: 2
key: 11,val: 1
```

**real output**

```
key: 11, val: 1
key: 11, val: 1
key: 11, val: 1
key: 11, val: 1
key: 11, val: 1
key: 11, val: 1
key: 11, val: 1
key: 11, val: 1
key: 11, val: 1
key: 11, val: 1
key: 11, val: 1
```

**main.c**

```
int compare(void *key,void *key2){
    int k = *(int*)key;
    int k2 = *(int*)key2;
    if(k==k2){
        return 1;
    }else return 0;
}

int main(){

 struct table*t = create(11);
 int arr[11]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};
 int arr2[11]={11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};
    for(int p=0;p<11;p++){
        int i = arr[p];
        int *key= &i;
        int i2 = arr2[p];
        int *value= &i2;
        insert(t,key,value,p, compare);
    }
 print(t);
```

**function.c**

```
struct node{
    void* key;
    void* val;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
};

struct table{
    int size;
    struct node **list;
};

struct table *create(int size){
    struct table *t = (struct table*)malloc(sizeof(struct table));
    t->size = size;
    t->list = (struct node**)malloc(sizeof(struct node*)*size);
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        t->list[i] = NULL;
    return t;
}

void insert(struct table *t,void* key,void* val,int pos, int(*comp)(void*, void*)){

    struct node *list = t->list[pos];
    struct node *newNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node *temp = list;
    while(temp){
        if(((*comp)(temp->key, key))==1){
            printf("%s", "key already create.");
            return;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    newNode->next = t->list[pos];
    newNode->key = key;
    newNode->val = val;
    if(list!=NULL){
        list->prev = newNode;
    }
    t->list[pos] = newNode;
    newNode->prev = NULL;
}

void print(struct table *t){
    for (int i = 0; i < t->size; ++i) {
        struct node *list = t->list[i];
        while(list){
            if(list->key!=NULL) {
                printf("key: %d, val: %d\n",*(int*)list->key, *(int*)list->val);
            }
            list = list->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are passing the same address for all the values and key here, so by the time you reach the end, the last value is replicated in all the pointers

```
int i = arr[p];
int *key= &i;
int i2 = arr2[p];
int *value= &i2;
```

instead you can copy the number of bytes from the location like below.

```
//newNode->key = key;
newNode->key = malloc(sizeof(int));
memcpy(newNode->key, key,sizeof(int) );
//newNode->val = val;
newNode->val = malloc(sizeof(int));
memcpy(newNode->val, val,sizeof(int) );
```

NOTE: you will have to handle error checks for `malloc` and `free` the memory once done.

Answer (score 1):

the problem came from the main function.

```
int i = arr[p];
int *key= &i;
```

Your key is a pointer to the i variable, not to the value in arr.

The right way:

```
int * key = &arr[p];
```

(same problem for the value)